# MATLAB - display figure only when everything has been plotted

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to plot a 2d finite element solution and am plotting triangle-by-triangle like so:

```
for i=1:K
    figure(1)
    fill3(x,y,z,c)
    hold on
end
```

The problem with this is that when I run the code, it literally draws them all in real time so I can see each triangle being drawn. What I want it to just have the finished figure pop up once it's all done.

My friend has coded the same thing except she's not having this issue at all and we can't find any differences in the code. My computer is very fast so it's not an issue of lag. I'm thinking maybe there's a setting in MATLAB that I'm missing?

Edit: I found the problem. Apparently, putting 'figure(1)' inside the loop makes a huge difference. I timed it with 'tic' and 'toc' and it took 54 seconds with the 'figure(1)' label inside the loop and 2 seconds when it was moved just before the loop. Go figure...

Comment: What version of Matlab do you and your friends run? In more recent versions, they aren't showing "intermediate results" anymore.

Comment: 2010a. Actually, I figured out the issue. See edited post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you start the figure, set the `visible` property to `'off'`; when you are done plotting, set the visibility to `'on'`.

```
h = figure('visible','off');
hold on;
for i=1:K    
    fill3(x,y,z,c);
end
hold off;
set(h,'visible','on');
```

Also, I'm not entirely sure how the event queue works in MATLAB, but I'm fairly sure the fact you have a fast computer is effecting this. You can simulate what's happening with your computer by using `drawnow` on your friends slower comp within the for-loop.

Comment: thanks this seems to work but it still takes the exact same amount of time to run the code. when comparing to my friend's version of the same thing, it takes about 1-2 seconds and then it all just shows up. Also, with the visible property, I seem to run out of heap space before it finishes

Comment: @user1799323 I'm fairly certain the `visible` property will have no effect on your heap space. If you're running out you may need to clear your workspace or restart matlab. Check system processes when running the code. Is it really taking up multiple GB when it runs? I can't imagine this is the case unless you're using a lot of `fill3`s.

Comment: There's about 128 triangles. I restarted matlab but actually using the 'visible' property takes longer than if I were to not use it and just let each triangle draw out in real time.

Comment: @user1799323 Well, there's a thread here that discusses the problem: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/171944. It's a little old but there are some other ideas.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I figured out the problem. Edited the original post in case anyone runs into this problem